# c++ dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

```
class CBase { };
class CDerived: public CBase { };

CBase     b; 
CBase*    pb;
CDerived  d; 
CDerived* pd;

pb = dynamic_cast<CBase*>(&d);     // ok: derived-to-base
pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(&b);  // wrong: base-to-derived
```

I know the "base to derived " cast is wrong. But what is the inside reason of it? What is logical reason inside? It's hard to remember this without more explanation I guess.
thank you!

Comment: [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class/5313716#5313716) Because a cat is an animal but an animal may not necessarily be a cat (it could be a dog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the derived to base conversion, you don't need (and generally don't *want*) to specify a cast explicitly at all:

```
CDerived d;
CBase *pb = &d;   // perfectly fine
```

The base to derived cast isn't really wrong, though you'd generally prefer to avoid it. The reason behind that is fairly simple: a pointer to base could be pointing to an actual base object or anything derived from it. If you're going to down-cast like this, you generally need to check whether the conversion succeeded. In the specific case you've given, it won't succeed, so what gets assigned (the result of the `dynamic_cast`) will simply be a null pointer.

Most of the time, you'd prefer to specify a complete interface to objects of the class in the base class, so you rarely have much need for downcasts.

Answer (score 6):

First, `CBase` must be polymorphic in order for you to use `dynamic_cast` here (that is, it must have at least one `virtual` member function).  Otherwise, you can't use `dynamic_cast`.

That said, the cast of `&b` to `CDerived*` is *not* wrong:  `pd` will be a null pointer.

`dynamic_cast` has the useful property that when the cast fails (that is, if the object pointed to by the pointer isn't of the target type), it yields a null pointer.  This allows you to test the actual type of an object.  For example:

```
CBase b;
CDerived d;

CBase* pb = &b;
CBase* pd = &d;

CDerived* xb = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pb); // xb is null!
CDerived* xd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(pd); // xd points to d!
```

Your code would have been incorrect if you had used `static_cast`, since it casts without performing any runtime type check, which means there is no way to test whether the cast succeeded.  If you ever need to cast down a class hierarchy and you don't know for certain whether the object is of the derived type to which you are trying to cast, you must use `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

A derived class can have more "behaviors" than the base class.  More member functions, more member data, etc.  If you cast a base class to a derived class, and then try to treat it as a derived class, you'll try to make it do things it can't do.  Because you are trying to make an instance of the *base* class do things only the *derived* class knows how to do.

Answer (score 0):

`pd` is a pointer of type `CDerived*`. So, `pd` pointing object needs to have two sub-objects involved ( i.e., base & derived ). But with this statement -

```
pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(&b);
```

Here ,`pd` is pointing to only a base sub-object. There is no partial way of pointing to sub-objects. So, it is wrong.