# Reusing base class pointer in derived class

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
Class A
{
   int a;
   somepointer* b;
}
Class B : A
{
   void func()
}
main()
{
   A* a1 = new A();
   a1->a = 5;
   a1->b = new somepointer();
   B* b1 = new B()
}
```

Now when B is created it contains A, I want to reuse the a1 created earlier, that is b1->a should give the value 5.How can this be done?

Comment: You have a number of syntax problems....

Answer (score 1):

Every instance has its own variables. You can't access `a1`'s members from `b1`.

Your code have many problems, and the general approach of using pointers like you do does not fit C++ (it looks more like Java).

I suggest you get a good book about C++ and start over. Learning C++ by trial and error is not   the best approach.

Comment: That was just a prototype to explain my problem

Comment: So there is noway i can reuse a1 in b1??cant i assign the pointer of a1 so that the b1 has same values as in a1's variables?

Comment: B* b1 = static_cast<B*>(a1); Since b1 is pointing to a1 now can i also access b1's variable?

Comment: @HumayaraNazneen You can do `B* b1 = dynamic_cast<B*>(a1);`. This will make b1 point to the same object as a1. But for this to work the class `A` must be polymorphic (it must have at least one virtual function).

Comment: @HumayaraNazneen If `A` were polymorphic and you would perform a `dynamic_cast` and point `b1` to same object as `a1`, then you could access `a1`'s members via dereferencing (`->`) from `b1`.

Comment: But wil i also be able to acces B's members with b1 with dynamic cast?

Comment: @HumayaraNazneen Hmm, actually I was wrong about the `dynamic_cast`. In your case `a1` points to an `A` object so the `dynamic_cast` will fail. When you know the dynamic type of the object then using `static_cast` is ok. So you would have to do a `B* b1 = static_cast<B*>(a1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are providing just prototype of what you want. So I will ignore about the syntax problems.

You can create a constructor in class B that take a variable of type A as parameter:

```
class B:A {
public:
    B(A *my_a) {
        a = my_a->a;
        b = my_a->b;
    }

    void func() {
        //......
    }
}


main() {
    A *a1 = new A();
    a1->a = 5;
    a1->b = new somepointer();
    b = new B(a);
}
```

You may think about dynamic casting as well: [C++ cast to derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class) . But unfortunately that doesn't work, so best way here is to have a constructor so that you can manually set the variables you need for reusing.

Edit: Since Humayara Nazneen wants to have effects that changing a1->b will not affect b->b, then A::b shouldn't be declared as pointer, which means that:

```
class A {
   int a;
   somepointer b;
}
```

When you assign b = my_a->b; it will be copied by value.

Comment: Here since the b is pointer to something it could also be class.Just copying the values like b=my_a->, gives me only shallow copy ryt? I mean if i change the value of b in class B, that will also change the value of b in my_a ryt?

Comment: Pointer assignment does not implicitly copy the underlying object being pointed to. In other words, `b = my_a->b` in this answer merely specifies that new `B` object being created will *directly* use the value of `b` from the previously created `A` object. If you want a copy, you will need to manually copy it (i.e. `somepointer* copy_b = new somepointer()` ...).

Comment: Thats exactly what i want.. If i change b here i want the b present in previously created A also to change. With this does that work?

Comment: Yes, it should do what you want. Keep in mind that as soon as the previously created `A` object is deallocated (i.e. `delete` call), attempting to use any members of `A` from your new `B` object will be invalid.

Comment: Deleting B wil delete previously created A's object?