# Dynamic down cast to abstract class (C++)

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I am trying to learn some object orientated programming aspect I know from java in C++. However I am having some difficulties in using `dynamic_cast` where I would use `instanceof` in Java.

I have a base class `Cell` and a derived (abstract) class `Obstacle`. I have defined it like this: `Obstacle : public Cell` and `Obstacle` contains a pure virtual destructor. Now in the `Cell` class I want to implement a method `bool Cell::isAccesible()`. I've implemented this as follows:

```
bool Cell::isAccessible() {

    Obstacle *obs = dynamic_cast<Obstacle*>(this);

    if (obs != NULL) return false;
    return true;
}
```

However I get the following error back:

> "the operand of a runtime dynamic_cast must have a polymorphic class
>   type".

What's wrong with the way I want to implement this? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with visual studio? Is it their error? (I'm asking because of the tag)

Comment: I am coding this in visual studio that's all. I get the error while coding but also during compiling (C2683).

Comment: Why are you casting Cell to obstacle in a Cell method?

Comment: This seems like a convoluted way to solve this problem. If `isAccessible` were a virtual method then `Obstacle` could override it and simply return false and this would no longer be an issue.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but the error is because your Cell class is not polymorphic i.e. it does not have any virtual methods. If you add a virtual method to Cell your code should compile.

Comment: Using `instanceof` in Java or `dynamic_cast` to perform type switches in C++ is something you should avoid in the first place. You are creating cyclic dependencies as the base needs to  know about the derived and vice versa.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cell class must have at least one virtual function to use dynamic_cast. Also, if Cell is your base class, it should have a virtual destructor.

You should make isAccessible a virtual function and override it in Obstacle to return false.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why a virtual destructor is required ?

Comment: @mraduldubey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is wrong. Generally you shouldn't need to cast to a sub type of a class in its base class. If you need it, it is likely a design error. In your case the code should look like this.

```
virtual bool Cell:: isAccessible()
{
  return true;
}

bool Obstacle::isAccessible()
{
  return false;
}
```

P.S. The cause of your error is that `Cell` class does not have a virtual method and thus it does not show polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. However apart from the fact I was trying to solve the problem the wrong way (by casting) why should Cell always have at least one virtual method in order to be able to use a dynamic_cast?

Comment: @tim_a dynamic_cast and virtual functions need some information to be embedded in the object, but this increases its size slightly, so C++ lets you choose whether to add the information.