# Directly type cast derived to base class to call overloaded function

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, overloading

In my code I have naturally, without thinking about it first, type-casted a derived struct into a base struct in order to call an overloaded function and later realized that it might cause problems in some cases (though I honestly don't know if and which).

My code goes as follows:

```
struct Base
{
    //some variables
}

struct Derived : Base
{
    //some more variables
}

bool func(const Base &base1, const Base &base2)
{
    //do some stuff and return true or false
}
bool func(const Base &base, const Derived &derived)
{
    if(func(base, (Base)derived))
        return true;
    else
        //do some more stuff and return true or false
}
```

The code compiles and the functions work as intended.

I have found tons of questions on SO and elsewhere about up- and down-casting, but they all involve using pointers instead of directly typecasting to the base class. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class) link the person directly typecasts, however, to the derived class not the base. There are no questions I found that actually deal with this problem directly, but I might simply not know what to look for, so please point me in the right direction in that case!

I assume (and have read online) that typecasting involves creating a copy, so `(Base)derived` will not simply return a reference to `derived`, but using the first function. Are there any other downsides or issues that I might run into?

Comment: Why are you casting to `Base` and not to `const Base&`?

Comment: You don't need to cast here at all.

Comment: There will be endless recursion without cast.

Comment: @ElohimMeth I didn't know I could cast like (const Base&) to be honest. But if I can, will it actually forward the reference?

Comment: @0x499602D2 As Elohim Meth already said, yes there will be an endless recursion without the cast. This is actually an issue I ran into because I accidentally forgot the cast in the first case...

Comment: yes, simply static_cast<const Base&>(derived).

Comment: I assume static_cast is the C++11 standard to typecasting now? Is there any difference to just using (const Base&)?

Comment: @phil13131 `static_cast` is actually available in C++03. If you see people using C-style casts it's because they have a bad teacher!!

Comment: No there will be no difference in this case. It's considered a good style to use C++ style casts instead old C style casts. static_cast is not new to C++11.

Comment: @user5254963 Thank you for the answer. I will look into that and find out the differences. So far I never stumbled upon any problems with C-style casts, but I assume there are some obvious ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `static_cast<const Base&>(derived)` instead of `(Base)derived`. It will forward reference, and correct overload resolution.