# My teacher is not type-casting the same way as everyone else. Does anyone know what he is doing?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, static-cast

My teacher included the lines below in one of our examples of casting. `c` is an object of class `Circle` which inherits from class `Point`. In my search for an answer to the question "Can I cast an object of class `Point` to type `Circle`?" I found that he uses a different syntax than every website I've been on. The websites all use `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` syntax. He won't be using static_cast and dynamic_cast on the test and I'm just wondering what he is using and how that operates.

Also, if you have an answer to whether I can cast a base object to a derived type, I thank you immensely.

```
output << "the center of the circle is at " << (Point) c; 
// casting `Circle` object `c` with type `(Point)`, calls the first overloaded >stream insertion operator"
```

Comment: [Casting base to derived is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class), that's why you use virtual methods instead. That is not the case here though, this is derived to base.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts casting base to derived with this syntax is ill-formed (i.e. `(Derived)b` or `static_cast<Derived>(b)` gives an error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(Point)c` is known as a "C-style" cast. This can basically be thought of as a brute force cast that does whatever it can to make the cast succeed. This means it could end up causing a `static_cast` a `const_cast` or even a `reinterpret_cast`.

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:

- const_cast
- static_cast
- static_cast followed by const_cast
- reinterpret_cast
- reinterpret_cast followed by const_cast

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

And from Stroustrup himself:

> Explicit type conversions (often called casts to remind you that they are used to prop up something broken) are best avoided.

and

> C-style casts should have been deprecated in favor of named casts.

*Stroustrup, Bjarne. A Tour of C++ (C++ In-Depth Series) (Kindle Location 7134). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.*

So the named casts are recommended. In practice I still encounter professional code using C-style casts simply because it makes code more succinct and readable and is -- if you know what you're doing -- normally equivalent to `static_cast` in the places its used. For what its worth I think C-style casts are okay if used for these reasons in a context that makes it *obvious* that it will result in a `static_cast`, and Stroustrup is coming from an overly object-oriented perspective in his general disdain for casting. But you should prefer the named casts.

Your teacher is probably using the C-style cast as a less scary-looking introduction to casting.

Comment: *"I need something less scary to teach casts... I know, I'll use the legacy  werewolf cast which can hurl you straight to UB-land if you shake it the wrong way!"* ah, C++ teachers...

Comment: Even though correct, I don't think blogs are great authorative sources especially when they are so  opinionated

Answer (score 3):

The answers so far didn't cover what `(Point) c;` actually does.  Assuming `Circle` does not explicitly define `operator Point`:

This is the same as `static_cast<Point>(c)`. It creates a temporary `Point` object which is initialized by `Point`'s copy-constructor, with `c` as the argument. This works because the base class copy-constructor can, for better or worse, bind to a derived object.

To be clear, it is NOT a reference of any sort to the `Point` part of the `Circle`. It is making a copy of the `Point` part of the `Circle`. This is called *slicing*. It loses all the "Circle" part of the information.

I would advise not doing this. The code would be better off without the cast. I guess perhaps there is defined `operator<<` overloads for both `Point` and `Circle` and he wants to explicitly select the `Point` one; in that case you should use `static_cast<Point&>(c)` or the equivalent `(Point&)c` to view the circle instead of slicing it.

NB. Deriving Circle from Point in the first place is also suspicious; inheritance should represent an "is-a" relationship (not "has-a"); but a circle is not a point.

Further reading: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score -1):

That is a C-style cast and will use "c.operator Point()" if available, otherwise it will behave the same as "reintrepret_cast(c)"

Comment: No, it will not do a reinterpret_cast here. `Circle` is derived from `Point`, so the cast does a direct conversion, just like `Point p = c;` would do.