# Casting from Base-Class to Derived-Class with ``shared_ptr`` behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, shared-ptr

I am having trouble understanding casting of `shared_ptr`.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class) does a pretty good job explaining the behavior with normal pointers, and the result is very intuitive - exactly what I would expect. However, `shared_ptr` show different results - I created 3 classes, one base and two derived and played around a bit with using `***_ptr_cast`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Base 
{
    virtual void f() { cout << "Base" << endl; }
    
    string name = "Base";
};

struct FirstDerived : public Base
{
    void f() override { cout << "FirstDerived" << endl; }
    
    void firstDerived() { cout << "FirstDerived only method" << endl; }
    
    string name = "FirstDerived";
};

struct SecondDerived : public Base
{
    void f() override { cout << "SecondDerived" << endl; }
    
    void secondDerived() { cout << "SecondDerived only method" << endl; }
    
    string name = "SecondDerived";
};


int main()
{
    FirstDerived fd;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bf = make_shared<Base>(fd);
    std::shared_ptr<FirstDerived> fdp = std::static_pointer_cast<FirstDerived>(bf);
    
    if (fdp)
    {
        fdp.get()->f();
        fdp.get()->firstDerived();
        //cout << fdp.get()->name;
    }
    
    FirstDerived sd;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bs = make_shared<Base>(sd);
    std::shared_ptr<SecondDerived> sdp = std::static_pointer_cast<SecondDerived>(bs);
    
    if (sdp)
    {
        sdp.get()->f();
        sdp.get()->secondDerived();
        //cout << sdp.get()->name;
    }
   
   return 0;
}
```

The output for this program shows (funnily `cout << fdp.get()->name;` is not possible because it will segfault):

```
Base
FirstDerived only method
Base
SecondDerived only method
```

Researching a bit further, I came to the conclusion that `static_cast` might be the wrong cast, so I changed it to a `dynamic_cast`. The dynamic version however will never return a valid value, even if I am casting to the correct derived version.

The desired result would be, that only if the initial object was of the type of the one that is being cast to in the next step then there will be a result. Else it should be null.

How should I correctly do this, is there a cast-version for what I am searching?

Comment: *"even if i am casting to the correct derived version"* - Yes it will. If it didn't, you were **not** pointing at an object of the correct derived version. Your pre-conditions in your test were wrong. Re-evaluate your assertions.

Comment: StoryTeller is right. The problem seems to be your assumption that `make_shared<Base>(fd);` makes a copy of `fd`. It doesn't. It make a `Base` object, using a `Base` constructor which can take `fd`. That happens to be `Base::Base(base const&)`, the copy constructor, because `fd` has a `Base` subobject.

Comment: I see, thank you. So there is absolutetly no way to achieve my wished output with the current status?

Comment: There's a very easy way in fact: just use `make_shared<FirstDerived>(fd)` to copy the whole `fd`. Remember that your cast is working on the shared object `*bf`, and not on the ctor arguments which were used to create `*bf`.

Comment: As i stated below, sadly, this is not what I am searching for. I cannot change the template argument since I want to store many different derived classes of Node3d in a vector, which i suppose is not possible considering your arguments.

Comment: Let me explain it via [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/4n9zYM); 

``FirstDerived fd;``
``SecondDerived sd;``

``vector<Base*> vec;``

``vec.push_back(&fd);``
``vec.push_back(&sd);``

``auto fdp = dynamic_cast<FirstDerived*>(vec[0]);``

 ``auto sdp = dynamic_cast<FirstDerived*>(vec[1]);``

 I would like it to work as shown in this demo usual pointers, but with smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the types in `std::make_shared` to `FirstDerived` and `SecondDerived`, respectively.
Also, `sd` should be of type `SecondDerived`.

```
int main()
{
    FirstDerived fd;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bf = make_shared<FirstDerived>(fd);
    std::shared_ptr<FirstDerived> fdp = std::static_pointer_cast<FirstDerived>(bf);
    
    if (fdp)
    {
        fdp.get()->f();
        fdp.get()->firstDerived();
        cout << fdp.get()->name;
    }
    
    SecondDerived sd;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> bs = make_shared<SecondDerived>(sd);
    std::shared_ptr<SecondDerived> sdp = std::static_pointer_cast<SecondDerived>(bs);
    
    if (sdp)
    {
        sdp.get()->f();
        sdp.get()->secondDerived();
        cout << sdp.get()->name;
    }
   
   return 0;
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1c8ssE).

**EDIT**
As requested by OP ([example application](https://godbolt.org/z/4n9zYM) without smart pointers), he wants to add smart pointers to a vector and dynamically dispatch the stored types. To do so, one can simple create a vector `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec` and add elements via `vec.push_back(std::make_shared<FirstDerived>(fd))` or `vec.push_back(std::make_shared<SecondDerived>(sd))`. Here is an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/6jP9K1):

```
int main()
{
    FirstDerived fd;
    SecondDerived sd;

    vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec;
    
    vec.push_back(std::make_shared<FirstDerived>(fd));
    vec.push_back(std::make_shared<SecondDerived>(sd));
    
    auto fdp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<FirstDerived>(vec[0]);
    auto sdp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<FirstDerived>(vec[1]);
    
    // true
    if (fdp)
    {
        fdp->f();
        fdp->firstDerived();
        cout << fdp->name;
    }
    
    // false
    if (sdp)
    {
        sdp->f();
        cout << sdp->name;
    }
   
   return 0;
}
```

This gives the desired output:

```
FirstDerived
FirstDerived only method
FirstDerived
```

Comment: Sadly, this is not what I am searching for. I cannot change the template argument since I want to store many different derived classes of ``Node3d`` in a vector.

Comment: @Nestroy I updated my answer. Simply push ```std::make_shared<FirstDerived>(fd)``` to a ```std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>```.

Comment: Thank you for your work, however there is still a problem. Let me explain my use-case a bit further: I am having a configuration XML file in which many objects are described. 
All of the objects defined in there are derived from the base class in my case. 

Now as I am iterating through the XML-file, I am saving all those objects on a vector of type Base. Since this should work fully dynamic, i cannot simply change the type before compilation.

Comment: @Nestroy This sounds like a job for a factory pattern.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing, but after some experimentation I can clearly see, that it does not work with normal pointers too. Haha...
I recreated my project in small [here](https://godbolt.org/z/c45KPx). Exceeds the scope of this post however I think.

Comment: @Nestroy I changed your Factory accordingly [here](https://godbolt.org/z/n8P8c6). It now uses smart pointers but you can easily adjust it to return ordinary pointers.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Do you have good source where I can read about the Factory pattern in C++? This seems really interesting

Comment: @Nestroy Unfortunately not. I used a similar implementation before but I didn't write down where I saw it the first time. But I am sure with little search effort you'll find good articles about it.