# How to deal with a covariance of base pointers, casting from derived to base class for using methods of containers

Tags: c++, covariance

I have the following classes:

```
class base{};
class derived1:public base{};
class derived2:public base{};
```

I also have an implemented container `pool` to which I have no editing access. In each of the 3 `.h` files, I define the following pool respectively:

```
typedef pool<base> basesPool;
typedef pool<base> derived1Pool;
typedef pool<base> derived2Pool;
```

At some point in the flow, I am getting an object out of the pool, and assigning it to a general pointer of type `base` with respect to a `flag`:

```
derived1Pool d1pool;
derived1Pool d2pool;
base* element;

if(flag){
  d1pool = new derived1Pool();
  element = d1pool ->alloc(); 
}
else{
  d2pool = new derived2Pool();
  element = d2pool ->alloc(); 
}
```

Later on, I am trying to clean using the following code:

```
if(flag){
  d1pool->free(element); 
}
else{
  d2pool->free(element); 
}
```

I am getting an error due to a covariance problem:

> error: no matching function for call to
> 'pool<derived1Pool>::free(base*&)'

An easy solution would be to define two pointers. I am trying to avoid this. Is there an elegant option to convert from the base pointer to the derived pointer? I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313322/c-cast-to-derived-class) and tried all variations of `dynamic_casting` I could think of to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you cannot cast (dynamically or otherwise) a non-lvalue base class pointer to a non-const **reference** to a pointer to a derived class, which is what is required as the argument to your `free` calls.

As you have stated that you cannot change the `pool` class definition (or its `free` member function's argument type), you could get round this by creating *local* (to the `if` and `else` blocks) pointers of the correct type, initialize them by dynamically casting the `element` pointer, and use those as the arguments to the `free` calls:

```cpp
if(flag){
    derived1* d1p = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(element);
    d1pool->free(d1p);
    element = d1p; // See note below 
}
else{
    derived2* d2p = dynamic_cast<derived2*>(element);
    d2pool->free(d2p); 
    element = d2p; // See note below
}
```

Note: The reason why I have included the assignments *back* to `element` after each call is that it is likely that the `free` function modifies its given pointer (probably setting it to `nullptr`, but I can't be sure). So, we need to manually propagate that change, because we have passed local/temporary pointers and the `free` function's changes will only apply to those.

Comment: You are correct regarding the `nullptr` :).

Comment: B.T.W, why go through the container pointer and not simply `auto d1p = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(element)` instead of `derived1Pool* d1p = dynamic_cast<derived1Pool*>(element);`?

Comment: @havakok Yep - I misread your post and incorrectly used the `...Pool` types. Edited.