# C++ polymorphism and cast

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

I'm trying to figure out the behaviour of polymorphism with casting.
Using the code below, are you able to explain to me why the "child > parent > child" instructions sequence is OK, and the "parent > child" sequence is not (chd3 variable is null after dynamic_cast) ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent { 
    public: 
        virtual void speak() {};
};

class Child : public Parent {
    public:
        virtual void speak() override {
            cout << "Yeah !" << endl;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // ----------------------
    // child > parent > child : OK
    Child* chd1 = new Child;
    Parent* prt1 = dynamic_cast<Parent*>(chd1); if (prt1 == nullptr) { cout << "prt1 ERROR" << endl;  return 1; }
    prt1->speak();
    Child* chd2 = dynamic_cast<Child*>(prt1); if (chd2 == nullptr) { cout << "chd2 ERROR" << endl;  return 1; }
    chd2->speak();

    // parent > child : NOK : raises ptrnull value
    Parent* prt2 = new Parent;
    Child* chd3 = dynamic_cast<Child*>(prt2); if (chd3 == nullptr) { cout << "chd3 ERROR" << endl; return 1; };


    // debug
    cin.get();


    // return
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot !

(Was expecting Parent > child dynamic_cast to be OK, because I found somewhere on the Internet that it would be OK if the classes have polymorphism.)

Comment: You can't cast prt2 to a type that it doesn't have memory allocated for. prt2 only ever will be a Parent*

Comment: `prt2` doesn't point to a `child`, it points to a `parent`.  You can't make a `child` out of just a `parent`.

Comment: A dynamic cast does not change the underlying type. It can just give you access to what is actually there. But in your second case the `Parent` is not actually a `Child`

Comment: *I found somewhere on the Internet that it would be OK if the classes have polymorphism*  Block that website and never go there again.

Comment: `Parent* prt2 = new Parent;` creates an object of type `Parent`. The pointer can't be converted to a pointer-to-`Child` because the type of the object is not `Child`. The first example is okay because `new Child` creates an object of type `Child`.

Comment: Does answer the question?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313322/14065

Comment: Side note. You must `delete` every pointer you create with `new`, exactly once. This behavior is different from other C++ dialects. Your current program is leaking memory.

Comment: The basic rule is that, with public and single (not multiple) inheritance [as in your code], `dynamic_cast<A *>(ptr)` only produces a non-null if `ptr` points either at an `A` OR an instance of a class derived from `A`.  In your code (1)  `dynamic_cast<Parent *>(chld1)` produces non-null because `chld1` points at a `Child`, which is derived from a `Parent` (2) `dynamic_cast<Child*>(prt1)` produces non-null because `prt1` is a `Parent *` which points at an instance of `Child` (3)`dynamic_cast<Child*>(prt2)` produces null because `prt2` points at a `Parent` that is NOT a `Child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of `dynamic_cast` is for it to examine the dynamic type of the object involved to determine whether the cast can succeed or not.

There's no need to use a `dynamic_cast` when going from `Child *` to `Parent *`. You can convert in that direction implicitly, so you don't need a cast at all.

```cpp
Parent *p = new child; // no problem.
```

A `dynamic_cast` is useful for going the other direction. You have a `Parent *`, but you're not sure whether the thing it points at is a `Parent` or a `Child`. So you can attempt the conversion with a `dynamic_cast`, and it'll succeed if and only if the object that it's pointing at is a `Child`.

```cpp
Parent *p1 = new Parent;
Parent *p2 = new Child;

Child *p3 = dynamic_cast<Child *>(p1); // should fail (give a null pointer)
Child *p4 = dynamic_cast<Child *>(p2); // should succeed.
```

Having said that, real uses for `dynamic_cast` are fairly unusual. The primary point of inheritance is to allow you to use a pointer (or reference) to the base class, but get behavior that's specific to the derived class, by declaring virtual functions in the base class, and implementing them in the derived class. `dynamic_cast` is primarily for cases where a derived class adds different functionality that's not in the base class at all.

```cpp
class Person {
public:
    virtual void speak() = 0;
};

class Child : public Person { 
public:
    virtual void speak() { std::cout << "I'm a child\n"; }

    virtual void squabble() { std::cout << "kids squabble\n"; }
};
```

With a hierarchy like this, you can have some use for a `dynamic_cast`. Any Person can speak, but only a Child can squabble. So you might have something like this:

```cpp
Person *p = new Child;
p->speak(); // no problem a Person can speak

// but only a child can squabble:
Child *c = dynamic_cast<Child *>(p);
if (c != nullptr)
    c->squabble();
```

But I'll repeat: uses for `dynamic_cast` are fairly unusual. If you end up using it much, chances are pretty good that you have a design problem.